# How to Apply HTTPS with htaccess to homepage only?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website that has a login section on homepage which requires HTTPS. For example if I go to http://example.com and try to login, I get an error message, but if I login from https://example.com then it works correctly. So how can I make only the homepage use HTTPS? I don't want the whole site to use HTTPS.

Basically after logging in from https://www.example.com I would get redirected to https://www.example.com/account-page. So these 2 places would be the only places with HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure you can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: this wouldnt work, All pages visted after would still be https, There needs to be 2 conditional re write rules

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Haven't been able to test this yet since we decided to do something else.

Comment: Oh ok np, good to know you resolved your problem. You can still mark the answer accepted so that future visitors can get benefited.